# при каждом создание flutter проекта не добавляется путь к jdk в gradle.properties

Tags: flutter, dart

При каждом создание flutter проекта не добавляется путь к jdk в gradle.properties использую inteliji idea, vscode.  Самостоятельно приходиться добавлять, что подскажете делать?
PS: Путь к jdk настроен, с git скаченные проекты работают, dart, flutter extension включены, IDE получили последние обновления.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Creating a new project
In the IDE, click Create New Project from the Welcome window or File > New > Project from the main IDE window.
Select Flutter in the menu, and click Next.
Enter your desired Project name and Project location.
If you might publish this app, set the company domain.
Click Finish.                                                                                                                                         
      Then I am finding out that there is not jdk path(org.gradle.java.home=/C:/Users/Zhake/.jdks/corretto-1.8.0_292)  in gradle.properties.

Comment: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` - ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2

Comment: _«C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2»_ - выглядит нормально... других идей нет((

Comment: После обновления системы windows все заработала, всем огромное спасибо.